# Apache Spark: Can the MesosClusterDispatcher run executors in Docker containers?

Tags: apache-spark, docker, cluster-computing, mesos

I'm working on building a Mesos cluster to run Apache Spark. I'd prefer to use Docker containers for my Spark executors and I can do that using spark-submit's client mode (with `--master mesos://mesosmaster:5050` and `--conf spark.mesos.executor.docker.image=myimage:latest`), but I'd like to be able to do the same with cluster mode.

I have the MesosClusterDispatcher running and can submit jobs to it (with `--master mesos://clusterdispatcher:7077 --mode cluster --supervised`), but when I specify a docker image for the executors to use, it seems like the dispatcher is ignoring the parameter and trying to run jobs directly in the Mesos sandbox.

Is it actually possible to combine the cluster dispatcher with `spark.mesos.executor.docker.image`? I was hoping to de-couple Spark from Mesos as much as possible so that they can be upgraded independently, but obviously I'll have to rethink my strategy if the cluster dispatcher can't use docker images.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check this out
https://github.com/wangqiang8511/docker-spark-mesos

it looks like it should work, although I had problems with it when deployed on a larger cluster.